# How to call a file line by line to pass commands over each line in the file using python?

Tags: python

```
import subprocess
import sys

f = open('IPList.txt')
for line in f:
    subprocess.call("nslookup", line, shell=True)
    #print (line)
f.close()
```

Above program doesn't work. Getting below error:

======================================================================

```
PS C:\Python34> .\Python testnslookup.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "testnslookup.py", line 7, in <module>
  subprocess.call("nslookup", line, shell=True)
File "C:\Python34\lib\subprocess.py", line 537, in call
  with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:
File "C:\Python34\lib\subprocess.py", line 767, in __init__
  raise TypeError("bufsize must be an integer")
TypeError: bufsize must be an integer
```

=======================================================================

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try putting all of the `call` non-keyword arguments in a list.

```
subprocess.call(["nslookup", line], shell=True)
```